# Get base64 string from plotly.js from promise

Tags: javascript, promise, base64, plotly.js

I would like to get plot as image in base64 format from plotly.js

This is my code:

```
async myfunc() {
      return await Plotly.plot('teams-trace', dataSessions, layout).then((gd) => {
        return Plotly.toImage(gd, {format: 'png', height: 1080, width: 1920});
      }).then((dataURI) => {
        return dataURI;
      });
}
```

I need to return dataURI as a string. But now it returns as an object.

Answer (score 3):

The reference for the `toImage` function can be found [**here**](https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlytoimage)

Try this refactor to your async func:

```
async function myfunc() {
  const gd = await Plotly.plot('teams-trace', dataSessions, layout);
  return await Plotly.toImage(gd, {format: 'png', height: 1080, width: 1920});
}
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/niiyeboah/pen/BaNLVdK)